# How to set WATIR focus on new window

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, watir, watir-webdriver, webautomation

I'm new to WATIR testing (and do I love it!) and have run into a wall on how to refocus my WATIR script to a newly opened window.. Here's my (simplified) script....

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
browser=Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto("http://0:3050")

browser.text_field(:name,"userkey300203830").set("OKJHNB")
browser.button(:id, "interview48").click

puts "Expected Result:"
puts "A successful display of cars"

if browser.window(:title=>"300203830").exists?
   puts " Test passed. New window opened!"
else
   puts " Test Failed! No window found"
end
```

It all works right up to the end.  After the key "interview48" is clicked, a new window is opened with the title "300203830". Looks like I find it but I just don't know how to now focus on that window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
browser.window(:title => "300203830").use do
  # do something
end
```

More information: http://watir.github.io/docs/browser-popups/

Answer (score 7):

Additionally for more than 2 windows you can use the following:

```
browser.windows[n].use
```

#n is variable for which window. n will access them in order of opened or tabs from left to right

Answer (score 6):

```
browser.windows.last.use 
browser.windows.first.use
```

You can use the above commands if you open a new window from first browser instance and would like to toggle between the two.

Comment: This one seemed to not fail when there is only one window present, as opposed to browser.windows[n].use. Just a tidbit of information for anyone who might be interested in that distinction.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 primary selectors for windows:

- `:title`     - typically the easiest
- `:url`         - often used with a Regexp value
- `:element` - a unique element might be the least brittle (new as of Watir 6.18!)

  browser.window(title: 'new window')
  browser.window(url: /my_page.html/)
  browser.window(element: browser.div(id: 'my-element'))

Locating by index is no longer supported

More information: [Watir Browser Windows](http://watir.com/guides/windows/)

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one other window you want to use, so as of Watir 6.18, the easiest way to work with that window is with `Browser#switch_window`. It can only be used if there are only 2 windows, and all it does is switch to the other one, no additional locating required.

```
browser.switch_window
```